# In XML what do you call this: //@Dohicky.0 and how to address it in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxp

It's my first time parsing XML and I don't really know what I'm doing at the moment.  Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyDocument xmi:version="2.0">
  <Thingamabob name="A" hasDohicky="//@Dohicky.0">
    <Dingus/>
  </Thingamabob>
  <Dohicky name="B"/>
</MyDocument>
```

So what is "//@Dohicky.0" called?  I understand the purpose, but I'm don't know how to deal with it when I'm parsing XML through Java JAXP.  I guess I could parse the hasDohicky attribute's value and then lookfor the 0th occurrence of an element by that name... but I bet there's got to be a better way, right?

Thanks All!

Comment: It's XPath syntax, right? I'm not sure what you're looking for - pass the attribute value into an XPath selector statement and you'll get back the element it's "pointing" to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's an Attribute (like the "name" attributes in `Dohicky` and `Thingamabob`)

In this case `hasDohicky` looks a bit like a XQuery string, though I am not sure about the ".0" part see [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) for more info about XQuery.